# Working with pointer as usize and manual alignment

Tags: c++, memory-management, rust, memory-alignment

I found this code in the article https://fitzgeraldnick.com/2019/11/01/always-bump-downwards.html :

```
let ptr = self.ptr as usize;

// Round the bump pointer up to the requested
// alignment. See the footnote for details.
let aligned = (ptr + align - 1) & !(align - 1);

let new_ptr = aligned + size;
// ...
self.ptr = new_ptr as *mut u8;
```

This unsafe code allocates dynamic storage for objects and does manual address alignment, using integer representation of memory address. I doubt if the code is correct for different architectures, for example on computers with segmented memory model. So I have questions:

1. Is this code surely correct in Rust, and if so, what kind of processor architectures Rust assumes, and is there any formal definition of it?
2. Is it possible to do the same in C++ without violaton of the C++ Standard? Namely, having pointer to free space with unknown alignment cast it to size_t/uintptr_t and align it manually?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align

Comment: Bump allocation presumes that a contiguous block of memory has been reserved for allocation in advance. If your memory is segmented, that most likely means that the whole block has to be in the same segment. But that doesn't have any bearing on this code.